# "label" field in the transaction list

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, listtransactions

Looking at this [dev reference guide](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#listtransactions) I found a returned field called `label`. Is this the same `label` specified to each key when using `importmulti`?